# Display Certain Words After certain time interval

Tags: php, random, words

I want to display these two words "current streams" and "top streams" using "php" after an interval of 30 seconds.

they must not to be random.. but like this:

- For the first 30 seconds the phrase "current streams" is displayed,
- In the next 30 seconds, the phrase "top streams" is displayed,
- (repeating)

I tried `srand(floor(time() / (30)));` but it display them randomly some time same word 2 times..!!
**Page Refreshing is allowed..!! Do not want to use javascript**

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far. And please, take the time to write a clear question - you do not need to use a thousand exclamation marks to get our attention.

Comment: If you want to change the word continuously you can't achieve this in PHP without page reloads. I think you need to look at javascript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for in-page changes (so no refresh) then you need to use JavaScript.

In reponse to your question:
Why not get the current time (seconds) and see if it's greater than 00 and smaller than 30 echo string a, else echo string b:

```
$datCurrentTime = date("s");
if ($datCurrentTime >= '00' && $datCurrentTime < '30') {
   echo "Current streams";
} else {
   echo "Top streams";
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code works great..!! but there is **syntax error, unexpected ')'** on line 2..!!
correct your answer remove ')' from last

Answer (score 0):

using unix timestamps in PHP would be easy for a non-javascript solution.
Unix Timestamps use seconds, so you can easily set it to work for 30 seconds.